# In deep space missions, how much of the journey is pre-programmed and how much is "direct" control?

Tags: trajectory, deep-space, planning

Regarding deep space missions, like the Rosetta mission, how much of the journey to the final destination is pre-programmed vs. recalculated on the fly? For the Rosetta example, was the whole sequence of gravity assists (and burns to align the trajectory in order to do the assists) pre-programmed, or was the trajectory recalculated after every maneuver? Could the whole journey be executed in a "hands off" fashion (not counting the other various stuff that needs to be done during the journey like doing science, telemetry checks etc., just the trajectory planning and maneuver execution)?

Comment: The "on the fly" usually means something between a couple days and a couple months before given maneuvers are executed. For example, in case of Rosetta, not knowing the shape of the comet they were unable to calculate the orbits ahead of time, but they created a plan of months worth of orbital maneuvers once the data became available.

Comment: @SF Well, of course the operations at the target are "on the fly" since we often don't know what the target is like (that's the reason we launch such missions). I was more concerned about the journey from the Earth to the target and the planning of it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The journey to the destination is about always completely pre-planned. All the gravity assists, close fly-bys, and so on, are planned before launch - and often long before the probe design is completed, as often the requirements of the trajectory influence design considerations: ability to hibernate, delta-V of the engines, tolerance to heat if the probe is to get assists from Venus, equipment to pick science specific from given targets-of-opportunity (asteroid flybys), and all equipment lifetime, as the trajectory means trip time.

This doesn't mean the probe can do everything fully autonomously.

In the mission plan, there are events of "course adjustment". Each maneuver, like a gravity assist, departure burn, or plane change is performed with a certain error. At these distances, a couple milliseconds of error at departure burn will mean hundreds of kilometers of error at the destination. After a maneuver was performed, the deviation from planned trajectory is determined. Parameters of the corrective burn are established, and the probe performs the maneuver at the pre-planned location and time, but according to parameters that were obtained only after the maneuver that introduced the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the course adjustment part is what I'm interested in. Who (i.e. the vessel or the mission control) measures the trajectory deviation and who calculates the adequate corrective burn parameters? Could the vessel itself do all of this (i.e. is there any kind of auto-correction) or does it rely on the mission control to do this stuff for it?

Comment: @zegkljan: Mission control. Probe position determination involves signal to/from Earth and is performed on Earth, plus the probes don't have the supercomputers the control center has to calculate the adjustment. Technically, if probes were equipped with doppler interferometry equipment and Earth ground stations would just bounce their signals without processing them, that would be doable, but rather pointless. [More on the subject](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/how-do-probes-locate-themselves/12138#12138) tl;dr: probe doesn't know where it is, control center does.

Comment: Would a deep space probe really need "heat tolerance" to get a gravity assist from Venus? I [naïvely] would have thought that the probe would slingshot at such a radius as to ignore such effect.

Comment: @Coxy : ​ I know very little about this, but would _imagine_ SF. is referring to the probe being significantly closer to the sun at that point. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: This is correct. Generally, dipping below Venus orbit distance from Sun requires extra considerations regarding heat management.

Comment: The Sun is hot enough to melt me at _Earth's_ orbit: I would certainly need an air conditioned spaceship to get as close as Venus.

Comment: Fun fact: about a week before New Horizons did the Pluto flyby, we lost contact with it. iirc (and this may be off a bit), we had sent a course correction or something similar to it, and it overloaded the probe's computer and put it into standby for a bit. It also took about 9 hours _each way_ to communicate with it, at that point. I can't imagine being on the dev/qa team for a project like that. :-)

Comment: You don't need anything like a supercomputer to do trajectory adjustments for a mission in progress. There's plenty of time available and the calculations aren't that complex; you could do them by hand. Computing an overall plan for a multiple gravity-assist-flyby is getting beyond onboard computing capability, though.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: agreed - although performing the probe trajectory determination is a rather complex task which would require some custom hardware on board.

Comment: I think you should better address the difference between "*pre-programmed*" as asked by the OP and "*pre-planned*" which is how your answer begins. These concepts are totally different and it is misleading to switch from one to the other. Why not take a moment to clarify? Of course it was pre-planned, and of course plans are adjusted, sometimes slightly, sometimes (e.g. Juno) dramatically. And of course not much is pre-programmed, although in some cases there is some pre-programming in place.

Comment: @uhoh: Interesting point - and I don't know, but "if I were them", I'd program in the complete route, at least to destination high orbit. Imagine the probe loses connection to mission control. The error may or may not vanish, but the transfer window will not reappear for years to come.